# Gulp autoprefixer, browserify and browser support

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, cross-browser

I am using autoprefixer and browserify with gulp. Is there anything else I should use for better browser support ? Also, why do people specify which browsers they want to support in autoprefixer options ? Isn't it wise to specify that we want all possible prefixes to be added ? And how would you tell autoprefixer to add all possible prefixes ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The more prefixes you add, the larger your CSS file becomes, smallest asset size is somewhat of a goal on the internet now a days.

Comment: That's the only reason I can think of too, was wondering if there was something else behind it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a CSS pre-processor I would advise on using a framework of some sort, like **[Bourbon for SASS](http://bourbon.io/)**. It is built upon SASS mixins which hold all the valuable prefixes that You need, without worrying if you forgot something.

It is as simple as:
`@include display(flex);` - this mixin adds like 7 or 8 prefixes for various browsers for Flex and that is upon pre-build SASS processing. This is the most accurate way of doing things in my practice so far.

You can also add an Autoprefixer plugin to your editor of choice.

Comment: Yes I am using gulp sass preprocessor. Sounds interesting, never heard of Bourbon, thanks for your info !